# Reading variable after space from console

Tags: c#

Hello i looking for help about reading variable from console, which have space separator between variable input in c#, like in c++.

c++ code sample:

```
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int n,k;
    cin>>n>>k;
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: `Console.Read();`

Comment: Refer - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/console-read-method-in-c-sharp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like the following:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int n, k;
    var input = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
    int.TryParse(input[0], out n);
    if (input.Length > 1) int.TryParse(input[1], out k);
}
```

This will split the input by a space character, try to parse the first two as `int`, and then put their values in `n` and `k` respectively. If either of the two isn't an integer, the value of the corresponding variable will be zero, just like in C++.

---

To make this more dynamic and accept more than two numbers, you could use an array instead. Here's an example:

```
var input = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');

int[] numbers = input.Select(s =>
{
    int n;
    int.TryParse(s, out n);
    return n;
})
.ToArray();

// Or a one-liner:
//int[] numbers = input.Select(s => (int.TryParse(s, out int n) ? n : 0)).ToArray();
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that it's a *very* good idea to check the result of `int.TryParse`. Otherwise it's impossible to know whether the input was actually 0, or if it's only 0 because the value wasn't an integer.

Comment: Thank you this is what I meant

Comment: @BrootsWaymb I tried to make the code as close to the C++ code as possible. In the C++ version, if the input is _not_ int, the value in of the corresponding variable will be zero. I'm not really good with C++ though so I might have missed something. Did I?

Comment: My point is that C# lets you catch bad input and act on it. C++ documentation such as [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/basic_io/) say it is very poor behavior and that `cin` results should be checked (although I don't know much C++ at all, so I'm not even sure the best way to do that). Not saying what you've done is incorrect, but C# offers and easy way to make this better, so at the very least it's worth mentioning.